# How to save a CSV file as UTF-8

Tags: c++, csv, utf-8, mfc

I write the code to create the . CSV files out there with Thai characters. But when I open a file using Microsoft Excel Thai characters in that file a wrong.But when I open it in Notepad, and then I press Save. And open it in Excel again. It is desired I think it is because the program does not Encoding to utf-8.
I had to do to Program, save it as utf-8.

```
std:: ofstream MyCSVFile;
MyCSVFile.open("myfile.csv", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
MyCSVFile << "Name,Address" << endl;
MyCSVFile <<name<<","<<address << endl;
MyCSVFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: If you store the data in name and address in UTF8, I would think they would get written out as such. (C++ and `<<` just write bytes out and don't particularly care about encodings.)  This just transfers the question to making sure your original data is in the encoding you want it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the BOM to the beginning of the file. Try this:

```
const char *bom = "\xef\xbb\xbf";
MyCSVFile << bom;
MyCSVFile << "Name...
```

This a good read: [BOM in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Is a BOM marker required?

Comment: Also I dislike this technique as you are required to read the BOM marker when opening the file to read. Is there not a technique in C++ that gets the file stream to automatically do this (ie some local object that the stream can be imbued with).

Comment: I would also note that he is appending to the file. The BOM marker may not be appropriate in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following (assuming the file path is stored in `FilePath`):
Here is the code you should use:

```
const std::wstring fileStr(FilePath);
wofstream mFile(FilePath);


mFile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
if (mFile.is_open())
{
    const wchar_t *bom = L"\xef\xbb\xbf";
    mFile << bom;
...
```

Now you can write the text, and of course close the file.